# Running sencha compilation without java installed causes "Could not open the pipe" error

Tags: java, javascript, extjs

I would like to be able to run a sencha compilation without a full java installation on my machine. I.e. I want to just include the java binaries in a tools folder. The only part of the compilation that doesn't work currently is the final part which compresses the js files. I'm getting the following error:

> uncaught exception: Stream:"Could not open the pipe" (exec://java -jar
>   "C:\projects\Tools\SenchaSDKTools-1.2.3\jsbuilder\ycompressor\ycompressor.jar"
>   --type js -o "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ext\WebApp\app-all.js" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ext\WebApp\app-all.jstemp-1098294810303.0708")

To try this out I created a simple js file which does only the failing step:

```
var cmd = 'java -jar "C:\\projects\\tools\\SenchaSDKTools-1.2.3\\jsbuilder\\ycompressor\\ycompressor.jar" --type js -o "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\ext\\WebApp\\app-all.js" "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\ext\\WebApp\\app-all.js-temp-1098294810303.0708"';
var stream = new Stream('exec://' + cmd);
stream.close();
```

then ran the simple js file using jsdb from a command line:

```
jsdb simple.js
```

When java is fully installed the above code works fine, when I uninstall java the above line fails with the error message above.

I'm guessing it's something todo with the java alias. I have little to no knowledge of this framework/language, so I'm hoping it's going to be very obvious to some experts out there as to how to fix this without a full java install. I.e. making the java alias know the location of the java binaries.

Comment: Well, you're trying to execute a java program. That does require java to be installed at least partially. Is there any reason you don't want it on your machine?

Comment: Very true.. We have the java binaries in a directory.. just not installed via the MSI wizard... So it's a case of how do I get the "java" alias to know where the java binaries are located.

Comment: Oh. For minimal impact on the machine, you should be able to just put the binaries in the same directory as you are running the command from.

Comment: Is there a way to make the location of the binaries configurable?

Comment: Oh dear.. seems it's as simple as updating the path environment settings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear... thanks to Jacob for helping me on this..

Add the java locations to the path environment variables and it work.

E.g.

> C:\JavaLocation\jre6;C:\JavaLocation\jre6\bin